# JAVA CORBA (BAD_PARAM) Null parameter

Tags: java, null, corba

I'm getting a `(BAD_PARAM) Null parameter` error when calling my method `opt2()`. My other method `opt1()` works fine. Here are their definitions:

```
void call1()
{
    StringHolder text2 = new StringHolder("bolek");
    StringHolder text3 = new StringHolder("a");
    S1 s1 = new S1();
    s1.a = 77;
    s1.b = 'r';

    i1.op1(123);

    String res = i1.op2("myString", text2, text3, s1);

    System.out.println(res);
}

@Override
public short op1(int abc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("OP1 " + abc);
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String op2(String text, StringHolder text2, StringHolder text3,
        S1 struct1) {
    return text+" "+text2+" "+text3+" "+struct1.a+" "+struct1.b;
}
```

`S1` is a struct containing an `int a` and a `char b`.

I get the following stack trace:

```
2015-05-04 17:34:24 com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0 writeString
WARNING: "IOP00110201: (BAD_PARAM) Null parameter"
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.nullParam(ORBUtilSystemException.java:1127)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.nullParam(ORBUtilSystemException.java:1141)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeString(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:462)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_string(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:456)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream.write_string(CDROutputStream.java:151)
    at edu.sr.generated.example1.I1POA._invoke(I1POA.java:58)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1680)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1538)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:920)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:181)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:692)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:449)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1211)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:471)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:500)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide the exception stack trace.

Comment: I couldn't add it to question so I paste it here  [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/qa2Q7jGL)

Comment: I haven't done any corba for some time, but it seems that op2 definition is out of sync between both sides, did you try re-launching the orb?